# NaNs disappear after saving to excel file

Tags: pandas

Missing files in my data was represented at 999, 99, 9999, so i used `df.replace()` to change them to NaNs however, NaNs disappear after saving to excel.

```
df4 = df3.replace('99', np.nan)

df4.to_excel('42003hnew.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Sheet1')
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, `NaN` is represented by an empty string when output is written. Use the `na_rep` parameter of [`to_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) to change this:

```
df4.to_excel('42003hnew.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', na_rep='N/A')
```